# Is it possible to renew Facebook permanent page access token automatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have generated a permanent Facebook page access token through developer.facebook.com for Messenger API.

Although it is theorectically permanent, it can be invalidated if Facebook think there is security problem.

Is there anyway to renew the access token automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If the Page Token is invalid, the User Token used for the Page token is invalid too. And there is no way to get or renew a User Token without user interaction. So the answer is no.